# remove validations dynamically using angular JS

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

Am creating a web application. It has a form with 5 mandatory input fields.It has 2 buttons. One is submit & another one is save for later.
When I click on submit, the form should validate all the mandatory fields & save the input given by the user. This is working fine for me.

When I click on "save for later", only the first input field should be mandatory. All other fields should be changed as optional. How to achieve this using angular js?

Comment: try dynamic binding of “ng-required” for Validation

Comment: You could probably call a function inside the ng-required and use a flag to determine whether it's a save or save for later action. In this case you should be able to handle the validation however you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [ng-required](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired).

> The directive sets the required attribute on the element if the
>   Angular expression inside ngRequired evaluates to true.

Example below:

```js
angular
  .module('exampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ExampleController);

function ExampleController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.required = false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='exampleApp'>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
  <form name="vm.form">
    <label for="required">Toggle required:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.required" id="required" />
    <br>
    <label for="input">This input must be filled if `required` is true:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="model" id="input" name="input" ng-required="vm.required" />
    <br>
    <p>required status: {{vm.required}}</p>
    <p>form error: {{vm.form.input.$error}}</p>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. Will try this.

Comment: tried the same code with 2 buttons. By clicking on save for later, tried to change the required value to false. Didnt work. Can you please help?
angular.module('ngRequiredExample',[]) 
     .controller('ExampleController',laterSave);
     function laterSave($scope){
       $scope.required = false;
     }

Comment: Can you create a plunker or similar code example that I can run to see what you are doing?

Answer (score 1):

View

```
<form name="Form" ng-controller="testController">
<input name="input" type="text" id="txtName" ng-model="Name" class="form-control" required>
<select ng-model="state" ng-options="s for s in stateList" id="state" ng-change="stateOnChange()" class="form-control"></select>
<input name="input" type="text" id="txtstate" ng-model="pincode" class="form-control" required>
<input name="input" type="text" id="txtplace" ng-model="place" class="form-control" ng-required={{isRequired}}>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-submit="saveAction();">Save</button>
```

Angular Controller

```
$scope.isRequired = false;
$scope.stateOnChange = function () {
if ($scope.state == "TN") {
    $scope.isRequired = true;
}
else {
    $scope.isRequired = false;
}}
```